# Getting first index of array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have an array that is not indexed from 0:

```
arr=([2]=aaa bbb ccc ddd)
```

I need to get the first index of the array. There are a lot of things I have tried and that work:

```
for index in "${!arr[@]}"; do
    first_index=$index
    break
done
```

```
first_index=$(awk '{ print $1 }' <<< "${!arr[@]}")
```

```
first_index=$(cut -d' ' -f1 <<< "${!arr[@]}")
```

```
first_index=${!arr[@]}
first_index=${first_index%% *}
```

```
ind=("${!arr[@]}")
first_index=${ind[@]:0:1}
```

---

What I **really** wanted to work:

```
${!arr[@]:0:1}
```

Given that this syntax works so well with arrays `${arr[@]:0:1}` and is very clean:

1. Is there a similar, cleaner way to do this for indexes as well without external tools, temporary arrays, temporary variables, loops etc? My attempts seem to overcomplicate such an easy task
2. What is actually happening in `${!arr[@]:0:1}`?

Comment: The loop is the approach I'd use, btw. It's verbose, but far more efficient than the attempts that use external commands. If you *must* use the `first_index=${!arr[@]}` approach, make it `[*]` instead so you're asking for a string explicitly, rather than asking for an array and coercing it into a string. In either case, you'll want to make sure the value of IFS is known.

Comment: ...there's no need for `index`, either: `for first_index in "${!arr[@]}"; do break; done`

Comment: (Frankly, though -- a good answer to the "what's happening on the preferred syntax?" chunk of the question would require tracing through some very hairy sections of `subst.c`; the people who are best equipped to do it live at bug-bash@gnu.org... though a question asking about syntax should go through help-bash@gnu.org first).

Comment: `arr=([2]=aaa bbb ccc ddd); index=(${!arr[@]}); echo ${index[0]}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My attempts seem to overcomplicate such an easy task

The task might look easy, but might not be a common use case and therefore have no syntactic sugar to make it easy, especially if you can use other built-in features to accomplish it.

You have plenty of alternatives, here's one more:

```
put_first_index_in () {
    printf -v "${1?}" "%s" "${2?}"
}

put_first_index_in first_index "${!arr[@]}"
```

> What is actually happening in ${!arr[@]:0:1}?

[Indirect variable expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

> If the first character of *parameter* is an exclamation point (`!`),
>   and *parameter* is not a *nameref*, it introduces a level of variable
>   indirection. Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest
>   of *parameter* as the name of the variable; this variable is then
>   expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution,
>   rather than the value of *parameter* itself. This is known as
>   `indirect expansion`.

With `!` as the first character, three possible things are supported: `${!parameter}` (the indirect expansion given above), `${!prefix*}`, `${!prefix@}` (expand to variable names matching the `prefix`), and `${!name[*]}`, `${!name[@]}` (expand to indexes of the `name` array).

The docs suggest that only `${!parameter}` supports further substitution, since it is only mentioned for this and not for the others. So bash tries to do the following:

1. Expand `arr[@]`
2. Apply indirect expansion on the string obtained from (1)
3. Get the `0:1` substring from the string obtained from indirect expansion

Since  is not a valid character in identifiers, we get that error:

```
$ foo=SHELL
$ echo ${!foo}
/bin/zsh
$ echo ${!foo:0:1}
/
$ foo="SHELL "
$ echo ${!foo}
bash: SHELL : bad substitution
$ arr=([2]=SHELL bbb ccc ddd)
$ echo ${!arr[@]:0:1}
bash: SHELL bbb ccc ddd: bad substitution
```

Thus, this will only work  with arrays of a single element, say:

```
$ arr=([2]=SHELL)
```

And as expected:

```
$ echo ${!arr[@]:0:1}
/
```